# Making TextField Scrollable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am working in Android Jetpack Compose.

I have three `TextField` in a in a `Column`.  I would like the third and/or last text field to be scrollable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

`TextField` example with `horizontalScroll`

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun Test() {
        TextField(
            value = "long1 long2 long3 long4 long5 long6 long7 long8 long9 long10 long11 long12 text",
            onValueChange = {},
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        )
    }
```

`TextField` example with `scrollable`

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun Test() {
        var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        TextField(value = "long1 long2 long3 long4 long5 long6 long7 long8 long9 long10 long11 long12 text",
            onValueChange = {},
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .scrollable(
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    state = rememberScrollableState { delta ->
                        offset += delta
                        delta
                    }
                )
        )
    }
```

more info there
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures?authuser=1#scrollable-modifier.

Comment: Great and thanks.  I struggled with this for some time.  Thanks so much, everything works great now.

Comment: Even better, you may use [`horizontalScroll`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#scroll-modifiers) modifier instead of the raw [`scrollable`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#scrollable-modifier) modifier. Like so  `Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())`.